# Manipulation of linux diskfree output

Tags: regex, linux

With the command: `df -h | grep /dev/md/dsk/d0` I get the following result:

```
/dev/md/dsk/d0   4.8G    4.0G   792M     84%
```

I want to manipulate this output to get **792M**

In theory, I could look for 1 to 3 digits followed by an "M" to get 792M

I tried to learn from regular expression tutorials but I have absolutely no clue how to get started and solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for editing this post to improve readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to get out the 4th element I would do:

```
 df -h | grep /dev/md/dsk/d0 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Comment: Of course, if you have awk, you don't need grep: `df -h | awk '$1 == "/dev/md/dsk/d0" { print $4 }'`

Comment: On the contrary, since awk's pattern field uses egrep-style regular expressions, I'm saying that your `grep` is redundant, and launches one extra process.

Comment: we seem to be at cross purposes. You do know that I didn't post the original question, right?

Comment: awk is awesome! Thanks for this input. I could even improve the line by dismissing the grep command: df -h /dev/md/dsk/d0

Comment: @Rob an upvote for improving the answer AND pointing out that I'm answering the wrong person!

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is probably the easiest tool for this.

```
df -h | grep /dev/md/dsk/d0 | awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

This will print the second-to-last column (in case the first column has spaces; I've never heard of such a thing in `/dev`, but I don't see why it couldn't happen; and it's third-to-last on my `df`) Or

```
df -h | grep /dev/md/dsk/d0 | awk '{print $4}'
```

to get the fourth field.